# Add a TapGestureRecognizer to whole view except UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview

I'd like to add a TapGestureRecognizer to cover the whole screen of a UICollectionViewController except the UICollectionViewCell cells.

The closest I got was

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
...
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapAnywhere = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addBoard:)];
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tapAnywhere];
}
```

Problem: When I tap a cell the prepareForSegue method is not called. The UITapGestureRecognizer seems to cover the cell.

Which View in a UICollectionViewController is the right one to attach the GestureRecognizer to retain its default cell "tap to segue" functionatlity?

Comment: Go with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701911/how-to-receive-touches-on-a-uicollectionview-in-the-blank-space-around-all-cells

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement Gesture Recognizer delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) //It can work for any class you do not want to receive touch
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        return YES; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Instead, I checked if `touch.view` was kind of class `UICollectionView` and returned `YES`.